# we need to show that that $f$ has an analytic extension to $C$

Tags: complex-analysis

$C$ be the set of complex number and $f$ be analytic on open disk $\{z\in C: |z|<1\}$, given that $\{\frac{d^n f}{dz^n}(0)\}$ is a bounded sequence , we need to show that that $f$ has an analytic extension to $C$. I must confess that I have no idea how to proceed. please help.

Comment: Probably you want to look at the Taylor expansion at $0$ and show its convergent for all $z \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: Hadamard's criterion gives the answer I guess.

Comment: ????????????????????????

Comment: @CityOfGod: Do you know what the Taylor expansion at $0$ is?

Comment: @JonasMeyer yesssssssssssssssssss

Comment: I would oil that keyboard, if I were you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson okayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is analytic on $U:= \{z \in \mathbb{C}; |z|<1\}$ we have

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \cdot z^n \qquad (z \in U) \tag{1}$$ where $$a_n= \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$

We would like to show that the series in $(1)$ converges for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, because from this we can conclude that the mapping $\mathbb{C} \ni z \mapsto \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n \cdot z^n$ is an analytic extension of $f$.

Since the sequence $(f^{(n)}(0))_{n \geq 0}$ is bounded by assumption, there exists $K>0$ such that $|f^{(n)}(0)| \leq K$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, hence $$|a_n| \leq \frac{K}{n!}$$

Therefore $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{K}{n!}\right|^{\frac{1}{n}} = 0$$

and by applying the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) we obtain that the series in $(1)$ is convergent for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.