# Holomorphic function extension

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let be $f$ an holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of $0$ so that its n-derivatives are uniformly bounded at $0$ ( $\vert f^{n)}(0) \vert < M$  for every $n$ with a fixed $M$). Then there is an entire function that extends $f$ to the whole complex plane.

My idea is:

for being $f$ holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $0$ ($U$) then:

$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{k}(0)}{k!}z^k \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{M}{k!}z^k $ in $U$

Calculating the radio of convergence of the second series:

$R=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{|a_{k}|}{|a_{k+1}|}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{M}{k!}}{\frac{M}{(k+1)!}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} k+1 = \infty$

And as the first series has every term $\leq$ of the term of the second series then its radio of convergence is $\infty$ too and the series can be extended to $\mathbb{C}$

Is this well done? also is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Don't you have any problem with the expression $\frac{f^k(0)}0$?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299288/42969.

Comment: edited. it was k! not 0

Comment: also the question you directed me was 100% the same, thanks